# Avalonia DataGrid and object[] how to tie

Tags: avaloniaui

There is

```
public object[]? obj;
public ObservableCollection<object>datatablew { get; set; }
public diztablew(object grps)
{
    datatablew = new ObservableCollection<object>() { grps };
    obj = new object[3];
    obj[0] = "1111";
    datatablew.Add(obj);
}
 how to tie
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="id" Binding="{Binding Path=?????}"/>
```

is it possible ? class grps not available at this location .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved part of the problem like this

````
public void init(object grps, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conns)
        {
            var testAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(grps.GetType().Assembly.FullName?.Split(",")[0] + ".dll");
            var t = testAssembly.GetType(grps.GetType().FullName);
            datatablew = new ObservableCollection<object>();
            string cluc = "select top 10 kod_rel,uet,rtrim(name) as name from statistika.dbo.statpra";
            var comms = new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(cluc, conns);
            var readers = comms.ExecuteReader();
            var counts = readers.FieldCount;
            while (readers.Read() == true)
            {
                var ooo = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                for (int i = 0; i < counts; i++)
                {
                    var obbjj = readers.GetValue(i);
                    try
                    {
                        var pps = grps.GetType().GetProperty(readers.GetName(i));
                        pps.SetValue(ooo,obbjj,null); 
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
                datatablew.Add(ooo);
            }
            readers.Close();
        }    
it remains to be decided
<DataGridTextColumn Header="kod_rel" Binding="{Binding ????,StringFormat=0;-0;#}"/>
`, how to bind kod_rel which is in ObservableCollection<object> , if I bet ```AutoGenerateColumns="true"``` 
then everything works as it should, but I need to define the columns myself .`
````

Comment: This is not the way to go Bob. There is no need for this kind of code for this kind of task. Have a look at Entity Framework and integrate your database through a `DbContext` model approach. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SryQxUeChMc

Comment: You are right, dear Jammer, for Avalonia, in Winform this problem is solved very simply, I hope Avalonia will come to this, otherwise it’s just an entertaining toy.

Comment: Everything worked out great, I was somehow slow when creating the columns in the designer and got an error, the columns are created programmatically and after the ObservableCollection is already filled, then there are no errors. With this approach, you can create a universal table, which significantly reduces the program code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't just use `object` as your data type. Make a view model class with properties. Such as:

```cs
public class MyDataObjectViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
   private string _someValueProperty
   public string SomeValueProperty
   {
        get => _someValueProperty;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _someValueProperty, value);
   }
}
```

In your view model for the `axaml` page then expose a property that contains your objects, like:

```cs
public class MainWindowViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyDataObject> _myCollection
    public ObservableCollection<MyDataObject> MyCollection
    {
        get => _myCollection;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _myCollection, value);
    }
}
```

Use data binding to attach the collection to an instance of a `DataGrid`.

```xml
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="using:AvaloniaApplication1.ViewModels"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
        x:Class="AvaloniaApplication1.Views.MainWindow"
        x:DataType="vm:MainWindowViewModel"
        Icon="/Assets/avalonia-logo.ico"
        Title="AvaloniaApplication1">

    <Design.DataContext>
        <!-- This only sets the DataContext for the previewer in an IDE,
             to set the actual DataContext for runtime, set the DataContext property in code (look at App.axaml.cs) -->
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Design.DataContext>

    <DataGrid Items="{Binding MyCollection}" />

</Window>
```

Comment: thank you, but I need exactly my option or the option of restoring the class from object grps.

Comment: No you don't since your approach will not work. Update your question with more detail. You need to have a class with properties in order to databind it to your UI. Using `object` is not the way to do this or any UI work really.